# how to pass object from richface Datatable to actionlistener

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I am passing an object from richface datatable like:

```
<rich:column>
<a4j:commandLink
value="Transfer inside Group" 
actionListener="#{adminBean.init_machineTransferInsideGroup}"
reRender="transferInsideGroupMachinePanel"
oncomplete="#{rich:component('transferInsideGroupMachinePanel')}.show()">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
            target="#{adminBean.machineToChange}"
        value="#{Machineassg3}" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
<rich:column>
```

What i am expecting from above code, when command link is clicked:

1. assign object (Machineassg3) to bean's variable (adminBean.machineToChange)
2. then invoking actionlistener (init_machineTransferInsideGroup)
3. after that richmodal panel

But steps that are happening is :

1. Invoking actionlistener (init_machineTransferInsideGroup)
2. assign object (Machineassg3) to bean's variable (adminBean.machineToChange)
3. after that richmodal panel

How to do expected steps (means assigning first and then invoking actionlistener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the rows variable with a `ValueExpression`.

Lets say you have in the dataTable declaration the attribute `var="machine"`, then in the managed bean's action method you could get like so

```
FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext elCtx = fCtx.getELContext();
ExpressionFactory ef = fCtx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
ValueExpression ve = ef.createValueExpression(elCtx, "#{machine}", Machineassg3.class);
machineassg3 = (Machineassg3)ve.getValue(elCtx);
```

I don't know the actual class of the `machineassg3` variable and so I just had it like `Machineassg3`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You should do the business job in `action` instead of `actionListener`. The action listener is intented to hold self-contained logic to prepare/preprocess the real business action and/or to log something, **not** to do the business job.

So, replace

```
actionListener="#{adminBean.init_machineTransferInsideGroup}"
```

by

```
action="#{adminBean.init_machineTransferInsideGroup}"
```

and remove the `ActionEvent` argument from the `init_machineTransferInsideGroup()` method. The action will be invoked *after* all action listeners (also the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` one) have done its job.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)